# Workflow changing Title an Name of the file

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to create workflow which can change the Title and the Name.

This workflow activate after create or change element.
I try to get something like that:

`Name - Identyfication_number`

The problem is imposition of the element. When I have do any modification of this file the title and the name looks like this:

`Name - Identyfication_number - Identyfication_number - Identyfication_number...`

How I can stop this multiplication?

I considered to use:

1. Condition in workflow
2. Manually activation (check the highlighted fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check if Title/Name already ends with the wanted string, and if so skip the updating.

1. Build the Suffix in a workflow variable.
2. Check if Title (or Name) not ends with suffix (using "If current item field equals value" action)
3. If thats the case update

[image]

Note that until you've selected the first item in the If the comparison is limited to "equals"/"not equals", but as soon as you select a text field you get a lot of options.

Comment: How I can do that?

Comment: See expanded answer